# Show value from every sixth column with a formula that can be filled down a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two Excel sheets. On Sheet A, I have several columns of data, and the average of each column is in row 41. On Sheet B, I would like to have a column that shows the averages from Sheet A. The catch is that I only want to show the average from every sixth column, starting with column C. That is, I want a column with the following values:

```
'Sheet A'!C41
'Sheet A'!G41
'Sheet A'!J41
...
```

How can I get these values using a formula that I can fill down the column?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, G is four columns away from C, and J is three from G. It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The basis of anything that should repeat every n:th column, row or similar is:

`=mod(columns($A$1:A1);n)*n`

Place this in A1, then fill it rightward:
`=CELL("address";OFFSET($A$2;MOD(COLUMNS($A$1:A1)-1;6)*6;0))`
... it will show absolute cell addresses in each filled cell, as in:
`$A$2   $A$8    $A$14   $A$20   $A$26   $A$32   $A$2    $A$8    $A$14 ...`

Comment: I tried the above formula but not actually working

Comment: I have modified the table named "menu" and now I need the values in new excel named "Products"  as like.. ; I need cell K2 in "Products" to display the value present on menu!f41, K3 in "Products" to display the value on menu!k41, K4 in "Products" on menu!P41 and so on.

Comment: to add to above.. f41,k41,p41 and so on are exactly after 5 cells in single row